# Simplify linq statment (Sonar2971)

Tags: c#, linq, sonarqube, ienumerable

I have this Linq:

```
MyCars refCar = m_service.Cars?.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == car.refId);
...
return m_otherService.GetCar(refCar.RefCardId);
```

**SonarCloud** is showing: **S2971 - "IEnumerable" LINQs should be simplified**

How to fix that?

Comment: Why are you using both ToList() and FirstOrDefault()?  You should only be using one.

Comment: this is some legacy which I got on my way during some implementation and try to fix this

Comment: why is `Cars` nullable? Can't it be an `IEnumerable<T>` (or `IReadOnlyList<T>`) type so it can return `Array.Empty<T>()` instead of `null` if there's no data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var refCar = m_service.Cars?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == car.refId);
...
return m_otherService.GetCar(refCar?.RefCardId);
```

If the `GetCar` method handles `null` values. Otherwise, pass a new empty object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess SonarCloud wants you to omit the `ToList()` call. This call creates a list of all items in the `IEnumerable`, but you are only interested in one item. The way you do it, you will loop over the complete `IEnumerable`. If you drop `ToList()`, you will only loop until the item matching the condition is found. Hence your code becomes

```
yCars refCar = m_service.Cars?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == car.refId);
```